# Show div and change text on link click is not working properly

Tags: jquery

The code below shows a div `.items` when the link with id "addItems" that has the text "Add Item" is clicked. But when the div `.items` appears I want to change also the text of the link from "Add Item" to "Hide". And when the link with the text "Hide" is clicked I want to hide the div `.items` and change the link text from "Hide" to "Add Item".

But its not working, when the "Hide" is clicked the text doesn't change.

Do you know how to fix the issue?

**html**

```
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="" id="addItems">Add Item</a>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
        <h6>Items</h6>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputName">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn mt-3"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

**css**

```
.items {
    display: none;
}
```

**js**

```
$('#addItems').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.items').show("slide");
    $('#addItems').text("Hide");
});

$('#addItems').click(function(e) {
    if($('#addItems').text() == "Hide"){
        $('#addItems').text("Add Item");
    }
    else {
        $('#addItems').text("Hide");
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting both of your click event listeners right after each other, which means you're trying to do both of those things at the same time.

Move your code into one event listener, and then work on the logic you need for the functionality you want from there.

```
$("#addItems").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".items").show("slide");
  if ($("#addItems").text() == "Hide") {
    $("#addItems").text("Add Item");
  } else {
    $("#addItems").text("Hide");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a single listener, like so:

```
$('#addItems').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $btn = $(this);

    if ($btn.text() == "Hide") {
        $('.items').show("slide");
        $btn.text("Add Item");
    } else{
        $('.items').hide("slide");
        $btn.text("Hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click method twice to the same element, you can  do this in shorter code see below

```js
$('#addItems').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let elem = $(this);

  $('.items').slideToggle(200, function() {

    if ($(this).is(':visible')) {

      $(elem).text("Hide");

    } else {

      $(elem).text("Add Item");

    }
  });

});
```

```css
.items {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" class="clearfix">
  <div class="form-group">
    <a href="" id="addItems">Add Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <h6>Items</h6>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName">Title</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn mt-3" />
  </div>
</form>
```